# Arduino unsigned long int to char*

Tags: c++, c, arduino, embedded

I am coding on Attiny85 with IRremote and SSD1306 libraries customized.

When receiving IR data the results are stored this way:

```
unsigned long                 value     // Decoded value, max 32 bits
volatile unsigned int         *rawbuf   // Raw interval in 50uS ticks
int                           rawlen    // Number of records in rawbuf
```

OLED display related functions are:

```
void printChar                (char ch)
void printString              (char* pText)
```

I am struggling with printing the received IR value to the OLED SSD1306 screen. User is able to review and save the received code to EEPROM and hence I have tried all different conversions but I am unable to print the results.value to the screen in a way that it would display the received HEX code (for example 0xE0E040BF which is Power on in Samsung television).

Due to lag of Serial in attiny85 I have no clue how I could debug this and get it working. Any help?

EDIT (adding relative code):

```
#include "SSD1306.h"
#include "IRremote.h"
...
if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {  
    dumpCode(&results);        
    irsend.sendRaw(buff, results.rawlen, 38);
    oled.printString("Received IR");
    // Print received hexadecimal IR code to the OLED screen
    irrecv.enableIRIn();    
    irrecv.resume();   
}
```

Comment: What's volative? Use `volatile`.

Comment: Fixed typing mistake, volatile (not volative)

Comment: You should show a snippet containing the relevant code.  Then it can be seen exactly where your problem is.  It will likely be related to the property of the `volatile` type, as by definition, they are usually tied to as external process, such as an embedded micro-controller and can be changed at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly you just want to convert a `unsigned long` value into an hex string, you can use `sprintf` for this purpose ([ideone](http://ideone.com/FgFTFZ)):

```
const unsigned int BUFFER_LENGTH = 16;
char buffer[BUFFER_LENGTH];
unsigned long value = 0xE0E040BF;
sprintf(buffer, "0x%08X", value);
printf("%s\n", buffer); // printString(buffer)
```

so that you can pass `buffer` to the `printString` method of the oled screen.

The format specifier `%08X` instructs printf to [format](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) the value as an hexadecimal number, with capital letters always showing all 8 hex values for the 4 bytes and padding it with 0s.

Comment: This appears to do the trick for printing but for some reason the data must mismatch, be different format or different lenght. The received IR code can be resent with sendRaw (powers tv on) but the printed value on OLED is not the value expected.

Comment: Maybe it's something related to endianness? Please check this out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: Your implementation need the the length modifier 'l' to handle the long correctly i.e. "0x%08lx"

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
int IR;
char hexadec_s[11];
sprintf(hexadec_s,"0x%08x",IR);
printString(hexadec_s);
```

I believe this should do the trick. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: it appears I was 4 minutes too late xD

Comment: This appears to do the trick for printing but for some reason the data must mismatch, be different format or different lenght. The received IR code can be resent with sendRaw (powers tv on) but the printed value on OLED is not the value expected.

Comment: This should work if your `printString` is well implemented.